# How do I call a method on a future instance inside of a method decorator?

Tags: typescript, decorator, web-component, typescript-decorator

I want to implement an `@listen(eventType)` decorator factory. It will return a decorator you can place on a method of a web component class when you want that method to be invoked when `eventType` is fired.

### Usage

```
class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
  //...
  @listen('click')
  log() {
    console.log('log');
  }
}
```

Code above would print 'log' to the console every time the component instance is clicked.

### Implementation idea

Add a call to `addEventListener` inside of the class constructor and replace the current definition of `disconnectedCallback` with a version of `disconnectedCallback` where `removeEventListener` is called, to avoid memory leaks.

### Implementation

```
export function listen (
  eventName,
) {
  return function (
    proto, 
    methodName, 
    descriptor
  ) {
    // add listener when element is constructed
    const oldConstructor= proto.constructor;
    proto.constructor = function (...args) {
      this.addEventListener(eventType, descriptor.value);
      return oldConstructor.apply(this, ...args);
    };

    // remove listener to avoid leaking memory
    const oldDisconnectedCallback = proto.disconnectedCallback;
    proto.disconnectedCallback = function (...args) {
      this.removeEventListener(eventType, descriptor.value);
      return oldChange.apply(this, ...args);
    };
  };
}
```

Albeit the method substitution trick works for the disconnectedCallback (and any other) method, it doesn't work on the constructor.

### REPL

Here's an interactive version of the implementation: https://stackblitz.com/edit/lit-element-hello-world-ec1lwz?file=listen.js

Comment: You don't need to clean up listeners like that. The browser will collect the element and the listeners at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

I would add a method to the class for registering static listeners.

```
export const listen = (eventName) =>
  (proto, methodName, descriptor) => {
    const ctor = proto.constructor;
    if (!('addStaticEventListener' in ctor)) {
      throw new Error('The decorated class must have an ' + 
          'addStaticEventListener static method');
    }
    ctor.addStaticEventListener(eventName, proto[methodName]);
  };
};

export const StaticListeners = (base) => class extends base {
  static __staticEventListeners = [];
  static addStaticEventListener(eventName, method) {
    this.__staticEventListeners.push({eventName, method});
  }

  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    for (const {eventName, method} of this.constructor.__staticEventListeners) {
      this.addEventListener(eventName, method.bind(this));
    }
  }
};
```

### Usage

```
class MyElement extends StaticListeners(HTMLElement) {
  @listen('click')
  log() {
    console.log('log');
  }
}
```

Comment: If the mixin is to avoid the method chain for performance reasons, I made a new version that avoids both the method chain and the need for a mixin. What do you think? https://stackblitz.com/edit/lit-element-hello-world-ouyx5w?file=listen.ts

Comment: I just don't think property decorators should be messing with the class prototype like that. The other class members are for the class and its superclass to define. Mutating prototype is also not friendly to the VM.